# NullReferenceException when ContentPlaceholder is within a LoginView

Tags: asp.net, nullreferenceexception, loginview

I'm new to ASP.NET (using 4.5, VS2013). Here's my situation.

I have a Master Page which contains a LoginView. Within the **LoggedInTemplate** I have a content placeholder. Everything works fine until, when on a child page, I try accessing a control via the code-behind.

For example, in a Page_Load eventhandler, if I try setting a label's Text property I get a NullReferenceException. After doing some searching on StackOverflow and elsewhere I tried moving this to the Page_PreRender eventhandler but I still get the same problem. **EDIT:** To make sure I'm clear, these are controls that are part of the content page, not controls on the Master page.

All content page controls/content load fine but any attempt to access them via code as described above ends with a NullReferenceException. Am I doing something incorrectly?

Comment: May you show your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to get to the Label (or any other control within ContentTemplate of a LoginView control) through LoginView.

Ex.:

```
Label myLabel = LoginView1.FindControl("myLabelID") as Label;
if(myLabel!=null)
{
    // Do something with the label.
}
```

This code can be placed in Page_Load event handler.

If you are accessing a LoginView (or any other control) placed on the MasterPage of the current page, the code might look something like this:

```
LoginView LoginView1 = Page.Master.FindControl("LoginView1") as LoginView;
if (LoginView1 != null)
{
      Label myLabel= LoginView1.FindControl("myLabelID") as Label;
      if (myLabel != null)
      {
           myLabel.Text = "Test String";
      }
 }
```

NOTE: If your label is in AnonymousTemplate and you're logged in, myLabel will be null, because it won't be added to the page.

Also I just realized that you have a ContentPlaceholder nested within the login view. I'm not sure if that's the right approach. I would rather have ContentPlaceholder on the root level of my control hierarchy and within it LoginView.

Something like this:

```
Master Page
   ContentPlaceholder
       LoginView
           LogedInTemplate
               Label
```

Comment: You were right about the ContentPlaceholder nested within the LoginView being a bad idea, that was the root of difficulties I was having. I'll restructure as you suggested.

Thank you!